# ¿Como puedo crear una función que se active automáticamente cuando cambie una variable de una clase, en Vba.net?

Tags: vb.net, poo

Esta es la clase creada y tengo creado un arreglo donde se encuentran varios objetos de esa clase, quiero que cuando cambie una de sus propiedades sea Xmax, Xmmin, Ymax, Ymin, se ejecute una función (o nose si se llame evento) que haga cierta cosa, eso es posible? Espero que me pueda ayudar, gracias.

```vb
Public Class Muros

    Public NombreMuro As String
    Public CoordenadasX As List(Of Double)
    Public CoordenadasY As List(Of Double)
    Public MurosVecinos As New List(Of String)


    Public Lista_Refuerzos As New List(Of RefuerzoCirculo)

    Public Lista_Refuerzos_Fila_Min As New List(Of RefuerzoCirculo)
    Public Lista_Refuerzos_Fila_Max As New List(Of RefuerzoCirculo)
    Public RecubrimientoRefuerzo As Double


    Public Lista_NoBarras As New List(Of String)
    Public Lista_LongitudBarras As New List(Of Double)
    Public Malla As String
    Public Capas_RefuerzoHorizontal As Integer
    Public RefuerzoHorizontalLabel As String

    Public MurosVecinosClase As New List(Of Muros)
    Public MurosVecinosDerecha As New List(Of Muros)
    Public MurosVecinosIzquierda As New List(Of Muros)
    Public MurosVecinosArriba As New List(Of Muros)
    Public MurosVecinosAbajo As New List(Of Muros)


    Public CentroideX As Double
    Public CentroideY As Double
    Public Property Xmax As Double
    Public Property Xmin As Double
    Public Property Ymin As Double
    Public Property Ymax As Double
    Public Property XmaxE As Double
    Public Property XminE As Double
    Public Property YminE As Double
    Public Property YmaxE As Double
End Class
```

Comment: Me podrías dar un ejemplo, te lo agradecería .

Comment: Te he puesto una respuesta. Pruébala ya que hace mucho que no uso VBA y no se si será correcta al 100%

Answer (score 0):

Podrías poner las propiedades como privadas, y crear unos métodos set/get para que solo se puedan modificar usando dichos métodos. De esa manera, podrías llamar al método correspondiente cuando se modifiquen.

Hace bastante que no toco VBA, pero sería algo asi:

```
Public Class Muros
    ...
    Private Property xmax As Double
    ...

    Public Property Get Xmax() As Double
        Xmax= xmax
    End Property

    Public Property Let SetXmax(Value As Double)
        xmax= Value
        // Aqui puedes llamar al método que quieras, ya que se ha modificado la propiedad
    End Property

End Class
```